# Incorrect query result

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a query which is not returning correct result:

```
 SELECT t.GroupName AS GroupName, t.ApplicationName AS ApplicationName, t.UserName
        FROM UserApplication t
        WHERE (@ApplicationName IS NULL OR @ApplicationName = '' OR t.ApplicationName = @ApplicationName) AND
              (@UserName IS NULL OR @UserName = '' OR t.UserName= @UserName );
```

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE userapplication
            (`ID` INT,
             `ApplicationName` VARCHAR(100),
             `GroupName` VARCHAR(100),
             `UserName` VARCHAR(100))
```

When I do not pass any value to the parameter then it showing all rows from the table while if pass any value to the parameter @ApplicationName or @UserName it is giving me same result. 
Please help

Comment: Third line, in the where clausal you type `@ApplicationNamee` with double `ee` that looks incorrect!

Comment: sorry that a typo mistake, I correct that

Comment: Please show how you pass values to the parameters

Comment: @peterm: If I only want to see the data particualr to a user only like 'devendrat' then I passed value like this : SELECT t.GroupName AS GroupName, t.ApplicationName AS ApplicationName, t.UserName
        FROM UserApplication t
        WHERE (#ApplicationName IS NULL OR #ApplicationName = '' OR t.ApplicationName = #ApplicationName) AND
              (#UserName IS NULL OR #UserName = '' OR t.UserName= 'devendrat' );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you correctly set values of user variables your query will work just fine

```
SET @ApplicationName = 'App 1';
SET @UserName = '';

SELECT t.GroupName, 
       t.ApplicationName, 
       t.UserName
  FROM UserApplication t
 WHERE (COALESCE(@ApplicationName, '') = '' 
     OR t.ApplicationName = @ApplicationName) 
   AND (COALESCE(@UserName, '') = '' 
     OR t.UserName= @UserName);
```

*It's a little bit more succinct version of your query*

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/07c6e/6)** demo

Comment: thanks peterm its working on query window but its not working in my report query window as its starting with SET. is there any solution in which it can be done through a single SELECT statement only...